# How to get first date and last date of month view

Tags: jquery, date

For first instance, this question looks like duplicate but it is not!

I am trying to find the first and last date of given month in a calendar.(shown in attached image yellow highlighted)

[image]

Example: In the attached Image

Input  : Month July

Result :

```
     First Date:28th June 2015

     Last Date: 8th August 2015
```

I tried below code

```
   var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
       months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
         Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
             return months[this.getMonth()];
           };
         Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
             return days[this.getDay()];
           };
         Date.prototype.getPreviousDate = function(beforeDays) {
           if (!days) { beforeDays = 0 }
               return new Date(new Date().setDate(this.getDate() -  beforeDays));
           }

      var date = new Date();
      var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
      var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
      var startDate = firstDay.getPreviousDate(3);//hard coded
      alert(startDate) // //This gives 28th June 2015
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkydgzr0/)
It works, but here I have hard coded value "3", I want to get it dynamically.

Help is appreciated.

**Solution**

```
           GetfirstVisibleDay: function(date){
               var firstDay = 0;
               var firstVisibleDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0, date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());

               while (firstVisibleDay.getDay() != firstDay) {
                   kendo.date.setTime(firstVisibleDay, -1 * 86400000);
               }
               return firstVisibleDay;
           },
```

Comment: So if it works with hard code where are you wanting to get it from and what problems are occurring? In other words...what's the question?

Comment: 3 is hard coded and every month 3 is not right number to deduct. In month of "May" i have to deduct 5 to arrive the start date 26th April

Comment: ahhh  I get it. Want the yellow highlight. First is easy   use `getDay()` for index day of week. So you know first of month I think you need subtract `(startDate.getDay()+1)`

Comment: I am thinking of making an array like this  [4,7,7,3,5,1,3,6,2,4,7,2]; represents the deduction number for every month